# Find POST URL from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url, post, curl

```
https://www.artsnow.com/Login.aspx
```

I'm trying to write a script that automatically logs into my account using cURL, obtains information from my account, checks that information against a previous obtainment to see if it has changed, and if it has, text my phone as a result. Since the form submit button uses some kind of JavaScript to make the POST, I can't figure out the URL to log in.

```
https://www.artsnow.com/Login.aspx?
ctl00$cphMain$chCenter$ctl01$el$UserName=my%40email.com&
ctl00$cphMain$chCenter$ctl01$el$Password=mypass&
ctl00$cphMain$chCenter$ctl01$el$LoginButton=[???]
```

After doing some research, the Javascript they are using is part of something from ASP.NET. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you not got the URL as shown above? Or is it the button ID you need?

Comment: I'm also not following what you need. The form posts to Login.aspx. The javascript it invokes is simply for validation. It doesn't change the form action or fire any AJAX or anything like that.

Comment: Are you going to send your password via url ? you lose it in seconds.

Comment: What would you suggest as an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is only using JavaScript for validation, it's POST URL is `Login.aspx`.  You may need more than a URL & field values to be allowed to log in though.  E.g. a valid session cookie.

Or it may insist on those hidden fields' values, the __CVS one looks important.  The system may be designed to force you to do a GET before a POST (e.g. so you can provide the __CVS value) to prevent unsolicited requests (XSRF attacks).

Comment: So, how would I go about logging in with cURL, then?

Comment: @Julien: I hardly know cURL, but I think you'll need to use it twice.  To GET Login.aspx and extract the necessary data required for the POST, which you'd then provide to a subsequent cURL invocation.